# SQL: How to find the sum of values where all the records has the same value in a column?

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

I have **Payments** table with multiple columns, including **Student,** **Value** and **Payment_type.** 
I want to create a query that will calculate the sum of values, if *all the records* of the same student have only NULL as *Payment type*. 
If a student has at least one Payment type different than NULL, that student shouldn't be included.

Example:

```
Student      Payment      Value      Payment_type
   1            1          100         NULL
   1            2          200         NULL
   2            1          200         NULL
   3            1          150         Cash
   2            2          100         Cash
   3            2          200         NULL
   1            3          200         NULL
```

If you look at the example, it should give me result 500, because the sum of values of student 1 is 500, and his/her ALL payment types are NULL.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select student, sum(value)
from payments
group by student
having sum(case when Payment_type is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: it worked, thank you.
what if i want to add one more filter criteria, like
Where Year=2015
??

Comment: Then just add the `where` clause to only look at records from that year.

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e58a/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Payments 
    (`Student` int, `Payment` int, `Value` int, `Payment_type` varchar(4))
;

INSERT INTO Payments 
    (`Student`, `Payment`, `Value`, `Payment_type`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 100, NULL),
    (1, 2, 200, NULL),
    (2, 1, 200, NULL),
    (3, 1, 150, 'Cash'),
    (2, 2, 100, 'Cash'),
    (3, 2, 200, NULL),
    (1, 3, 200, NULL)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select student, sum(value)
from payments
group by student
having max(Payment_type) IS NULL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e58a/1/0)**:

```
| Student | sum(value) |
|---------|------------|
|       1 |        500 |
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select 
    student, sum(value)
from 
    payments
group by 
    student
having sum
   (case when Payment_type is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this is very clean, plus semantically accurate regarding your description:

```
  SELECT student, SUM(value)
    FROM payments p1
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM payments p2
                      WHERE p2.student = p1.student
                        AND Payment_type IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY student
```